# How to check if the user is idle and switch tabs? via script (Google Spreadsheet - GAS)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a Google Spreadsheet and custom function needs to be like this.

1. Display dialog if the user is idle for 2 mins.
2. If the user switch to other tab and visited back the spreadsheet, display a dialog.
3. Upon opening Display a dialog. (Done)

---

- Tried to add `$(window).on('unload', e => {...` but it is not working on .gs only in html.
- Not sure if I can run the HTML without display just to run the `$(window).on('unload', e => {...` but I guess this is not possible
- Tried to use cookies for idle but not applicable too

Comment: I don't think you can call client-side code without displaying a UI element first (a sidebar or a dialog). The alternative would be to write a Chrome extension that can inject JS code into the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, this is currently not possible to do via Google Apps Script.*

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for the Sheets API and that you would like to request they implement it. Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services. The page to file a Feature Request for Apps Script is [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).

#### References:

- [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)
- [Apps Script Feature Request Direct Link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).